# How can I overwrite ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom in Openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I want to overwrite this interaction because on my tablet when I dbl click while map is moving (using this example http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/geolocation-orientation.html) what happens is that map zoom and jump to marker , but I noticed if I use `view.setResolution(newResolution);` then it zooms nicely without any "jumps".

so I want to overwrite the interaction to run the code above.

Comment: Do you mean, disable it? Or you want another action?

Comment: Would you be able to review this [Meta advice](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353) on structuring your question to attract potential answerers, please?

Comment: I believe you can just supply your own version of the function using prototype. Could you clarify what you are trying to do in a bit more detail.

Comment: I want that when dblclicking on map to run this code : view.setResolution(newResolution);

Comment: Any feedback ... ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe that way

```
test= new ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom({delta:0});
map.addInteraction(test);

map.on('dblclick', function(evt) {
 ...do something else with dblclick...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It is simple as this:

```
map.on('dblclick', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();

    olview.setResolution(resolut);
});
```